# Finding Current through element that offers some resistance and only permits current in one direction

Tags: current-measurement, electrical

Suppose
An alternating voltage e=200sin(314t) is applied to a device that show a resistance of 20 ohm and only permits the current in only one direction and entirely preventing the current the flows in another direction then the value of the current through resistance would be...i simply put use ohm law but the answer is wrong i.e 200/20=10A..And what would be the average value then...any one have any conceptual idea..thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

The peak current would be determined by the peak voltage (200 volts) and the resistance and, that would produce 10 amps (peak). However, I think the question might be asking about the average current flowing through the device. The device I would assume to be a perfect rectifier diode in series with 20 ohms and so the current would be a half wave rectified sine wave of peak value 20 amps.

Theory tells us that a half wave rectified signal has an average value that is 0.318 x peak value: -

[image]

Comment: thank you for your kind interest i am confused so that's why  i asked the question..the answer of the question is mean the current is equal to 5A so how this something is possible i mean how the 5A comes could you provide or give mathematical solution.would be very thankful.

Comment: @mtg given the question you asked, the peak current is 10 amps and the average current is 3.183 amps. I don't see how the current could be 5 amps based on your question.

Comment: i also confused how the result could be 5A ...the question is from the book which is objective type for the electrical engineering students..the answer they mentioned is 5A..

Answer (score 0):

We are not here to do your homework for you.

However, you can figure this out yourself.  Start with just the voltage source and the resistor, and figure out the current.  Note that 200 is the *peak* voltage, not the average or RMS.  Think about this carefully.  When someone just asks about "current", is that implied to mean peak, peak to peak, RMS, average, or something else?

Once you have decided what the current thru the resistor is, then apply the fact that this current only flows in one direction.  What fraction of the overall current is that?  From that, you can find the current with the ideal diode in series.